# Android: update the GUI based on events triggered from other threads

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface

I have a Button view that I want to disable from a thread different than the thread that created it. I am getting the following error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
Process: org.pcgod.mumbleclient, PID: 21302
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:8129)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:1258)
at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:5430)
at android.view.View.invalidateInternal(View.java:13927)
at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:13863)
at android.view.View.invalidateDrawable(View.java:18097)
at android.widget.TextView.invalidateDrawable(TextView.java:6177)
at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableContainer.invalidateDrawable(DrawableContainer.java:377)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:844)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setVisible(Drawable.java:1575)
at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableContainer.selectDrawable(DrawableContainer.java:448)
at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.onStateChange(StateListDrawable.java:104)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setState(Drawable.java:1413)
at android.view.View.drawableStateChanged(View.java:18264)
at android.widget.TextView.drawableStateChanged(TextView.java:4505)
at android.view.View.refreshDrawableState(View.java:18328)
at android.view.View.setEnabled(View.java:8018)
at android.widget.TextView.setEnabled(TextView.java:1895)
at org.pcgod.mumbleclient.Matar.TcpClient.readMessageFromServer(TcpClient.java:103)
at org.pcgod.mumbleclient.Matar.home$requestsQueueConnectTask.doInBackground(home.java:297)
at org.pcgod.mumbleclient.Matar.home$requestsQueueConnectTask.doInBackground(home.java:276)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Here is my code:

```
requestBTN = (Button) findViewById(R.id.requestBTN);
new requestsQueueConnectTask().execute(""); //handle requests queueing
```

How to work around this? I need to update the GUI based on events triggered from other threads (from `Asynctask`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use AsyncTask, it goes through 4 steps in order.
1. onPreExecute()
2. doInBackground()
3. onProgressUpdate()
4. onPostExecute()

In these 4 methods, only **doInBackground() runs on background thread, 3 others run on main UI thread**. You should update your UI elements (i.e: disable Button) in these 3 methods which depends on your app behavior.
You are not allowed to update UI on *doInBackground()*.